# openstack devstack neutron plugins install error What should I do to make the installation work?

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

My devstack has a typo during installation and installation plugins error, what can I do to fix this error
mysystem is Linux Ubuntu 5.15.0-76-generic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BscTb.png)
I have tried various SSH software and encountered formatting errors. I have tried unstack and clean scripts multiple times, but none of them worked，l also tried to rewrite the hosts file`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3lIn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk7P2.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's important to use a throwaway VM to install devstack, you should never do it on your host (which I don't know if it's the case).

To ensure you have the best deployment experience I suggest you use either the latest Centos or Ubuntu LTS versions (For Ubuntu it would be 22.04). The reason for this is that Devstack is used to develop the latest features for Openstack and we usually deploy it from Devstack master branch, therefore an updated system is key. In my experience, I deploy Devstack using the following guide [0]. However, you can always adapt the `local.conf` file to you own needs, depending on what you want to use Devstack for.

[0] https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/contributor/testing/ml2_ovn_devstack.html